# Join + While loop only outputting one result

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop

I am trying to make a quiz and am using the following to compare the results, it seems to work and outputs once but that's all it does, I don't get any more records processed even though there are two question in the quiz, so it should be outputting correct, correct or correct, incorrect etc.

```
          <?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    // Construct our join query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz a, itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions
    q WHERE a.quizID='$quizID' AND a.userID='$userID' and q.quizID=a.quizID and
    a.quizselectanswer = q.correctanswer" or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


    // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if ($row['correctanswer'] == $row['quizselectanswer']){
            echo 'CORRECT';}
            else { echo 'INCORRECT';
            }

        echo "<br />";
    }
    ?>
```

EDIT >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Table structures as follows >>

itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz
cf_id ,  cf_uid  ,  cf_created  ,  cf_modified  ,  cf_ipaddress,    cf_user_id,     questionID, quizselectanswer    ,quizID ,userID

itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions
cf_id   ,cf_uid,cf_created  ,cf_modified,   cf_ipaddress,   cf_user_id, quizID, questionID, quizquestion,   quizanswer1,    quizanswer2,    quizanswer3,    quizanswer4,    questionformat  ,correctanswer

Comment: You're duplicating logic in the query and php... the query will only return correct answers, then you check if answers are correct in php. e.g. your php can NEVER display 'incorrect', since only correct records would ever be returned.

Comment: Even if I remove the IF statement I still only get one row too

Comment: no, you should be removing the `a.quizselectanswer = q.correctanswer` part from the query, so you'll get correct AND incorrect answers.

Comment: can you please run this query into mysql database and see how many results you get

Comment: If I remove the a.quizselectanswer = q.correctanswer, I then get INCORRECT INCORRECT INCORRECT CORRECT, but there are only two records....... :-S

Comment: Please do not `SELECT *`; it is poor practice. Always specify a column list.

Comment: Please post your table structures.  It sounds like you are returning 4 records because there are 2 records for each quiz, one for each answer.  Is this correct?  If there is an answer ID, you may need to match on that also.  Without knowing your table structures it is hard to know.  It sounds like you are getting 2 x 2 = 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting four answers when removing the selectanswer=correctanswer condition (which is indeed not what you want, since you want to fetch both correct and incorrect answers) because you don't relate the answer ids.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz a, itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions
q WHERE a.quizID='$quizID' AND a.userID='$userID' and q.quizID=a.quizID and
a.quizselectanswer = q.correctanswer" or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```

should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM itsnb_chronoforms_data_answerquiz a, itsnb_chronoforms_data_createquestions
q WHERE a.quizID='$quizID' AND a.userID='$userID' and q.quizID=a.quizID and
a.questionID = q.questionID" or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```

You were getting a cross product of questionIDs without that condition. The four records you were seeing being (if the questionIDs are 1 and 2):

1. a.questionID=1 and q.questionID=1
2. a.questionID=1 and q.questionID=2 (don't want this)
3. a.questionID=2 and q.questionID=1 (or this)
4. a.questionID=2 and q.questionID=2

Comment: Thanks for your help, that has fixed it ! :-)